# Website scaling and fixed width - nothing is working

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with setting a fixed width and height for my webpage. I would like it to work more like Facebook where the page does not change its content when the browser is minimized or scrolled in.

I am currently making an IR for class but am stuck on this issue. Here is my website link: [2011.ispace.ci.fsu.edu/~ajb09f/ir](http://2011.ispace.ci.fsu.edu/~ajb09f/ir)

I have tried setting the width of the body to 945 and tried setting the position to absolute but it is still scaling. I know this is simple and would really appreciate anyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Make a wrapper class in css:

```
.wrapper {
  width:945px; 
  margin:0 auto;

}
```

in your page's html put all the content in a `<div class="wrapper"></div>`

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You got the wrapper with 945px of width. But its content is bigger. Like up 1100+

Why so?

Use `width:100%` on a children element if you want it to take the same width as the parent. That's point one.

Two: remove file `css/bootstrap-responsive.css` from header, so the site won't be responsive anymore.

Comment: Thank you Joe and Kevin. You guys are very appreciated. It turned out to be what Kevin said. That I needed to remove the bootstrap-responsive.css. Thank you guys so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in some cases your margins are causing problems. If you want to set explicit widths for block elements you have to make sure they don't add up to more than the width of the container or they will overflow. Try using percents instead of pixels for setting width.

Your floats look like they could be causing trouble too. Make sure you clear your floats as necessary.

Comment: Nick, thanks for the suggestion. I am still continuing to learn so would you mind explaining a little more exactly what you mean? Perhaps an example of where it overflows? Thanks again

Comment: please explain it properly.

Comment: So, for instance your `#wrapper` has an explicit width of `945px`, but your `.container` for your head has a width of `1170px`. Since the `#wrapper` is not wide enough for the `.container`, it overflows and escapes the boundaries of the `#wrapper` breaking how some things work positioning wise.

Comment: Oh, okay. I understand now. I will definitely fix that. Thanks